# Phonegap app using localstorage function error

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, local-storage

I'm trying to use this function with the HTML button (see code below):

```
function addTestBooks(form) {
  alert("initating addtestbook");
  var formTestBooks = form.addtestbook.value;
  if (formTestBooks == "Add Test Books") {
    var bookNumber = "2";
    var bookTitle = "De Valse Dageraad";
    var BookAuthor = "Jan van Aken";
    var bookGenre = "History";
    var comment = "Leuk boek";
    var addNewKeyValue = bookTitle + "_" + bookAuthor + "_" + bookGenre + "_" + comment;
    window.localStorage.setItem(bookNumber, addNewKeyValue);

    var realtest = window.localStorage.getItem(bookNumber);
    alert("  You added:  " + realtest);
  } else {
    alert("Error executing addTestBooks");
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form id="addnew" name="myform" method="GET">
  <input type="button" class="" name="addtestbook" Value="Add Test Books" onClick="addTestBooks(this.form)">
</form>
```

When I click on the button I get the error from the else 'section' of the code, `Error executing addTestBooks`. I'm not sure why this happens because my other localstorage functions are working properly. (Some of them look almost the same even..) I even tried clearing localstorage before I used the function but with no success.
(I only show the relevant code here)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you var BookAuthor but you are using bookAuthor later on, see lowercase b in book